# переменная $_COOKIE в sql запросе

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cookie

Не могу разобраться что не так написал.

Слова ПРАВИЛЬНО и НЕПРАВИЛЬНО выводятся корректно при соблюдении соответствующих условий, а вот запрос выполняется только второй: когда `TRUE` - нынешнее время не устанавливается. Помогите пожалуйста

```
if(@$_REQUEST['wordtranslate']==@$_COOKIE['translate']) {
    echo "<h3 style='text-align:center;'>Правильно</h3>";
    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE words SET ourdataword=(NOW()) WHERE    word='".$_COOKIE['slovo']."'");
} else {
    echo "<h3 style='text-align:center;'>Неправильно</h3>";
    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE words SET ourdataword=(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) WHERE word='".$_COOKIE['slovo']."'");
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Советую хранить время в `unix`.

Comment: После else поставьте открывающуюся скобку

Comment: она в коде есть, это здесь при редактировании случайно удалилась. Спасибо

Comment: 1) куки можно подделать и сломать ваш запрос (точнее - сделать с ним что угодно, можно даже все таблицы удалить), поэтому их надо проверять 2) а почему вы решили что только второй запрос выполняется? попробуйте вместо выполнения запроса просто вывести его на экран и ручками выполнить в базе, тогда и ошибку увидите (можно и средствами php на ошибку посмотреть, но пока ручками будет проще)

Answer (score 1):

Логично предположить, что условие `WHERE word='".$_COOKIE['slovo']."'` выполняется только в одном из случаев. Проверить можете только вы.

Отлаживайтесь: для отладки выводите *полный текст запроса* перед тем как его выполнить.

```
$sql = '…';
echo $sql; // debug print
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

http://phpfaq.ru/debug

Answer (score 0):

Не забывайте экранировать данные, которые передаете в SQL-запросе

```
$slovo = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_COOKIE['slovo']);
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE words SET ourdataword=(NOW()) WHERE    word='".$slovo."'");
```

Comment: При update кеш не учитывается. И даже больше, все результаты запросов, связанные с обновляемой таблицей будут удалены из кеша.

Comment: Верное замечание, я был не внимателен.